# What site should this question be on?

Tags: discussion, closing

Here is a link to the question (on Arqade) - [link](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/407649/valorant-on-steam)

Here is a link to the question (on GameDev SE - [link](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/210436/valorant-on-steam)

---

Here is the question:

> Has Riot Games ever said anything about putting VALORANT on Steam?
> Have there ever been any rumours about doing so? If so, when was this,
> and what was said?
>
> I know VALORANT is available on Windows, which is what I play it on,
> but it's not on other OSs (to my knowledge).
>
> Recently, I think, there were some rumours about putting VALORANT on
> Linux (pretty sure there's a YouTube video about it)... I'm not sure
> how true that it, considering Linux is much less popular than other
> OSs (at least, I think it is).
>
> ---
>
> Also, have they ever said anything about why it's not on Steam, considering they would be able to greatly expand their playerbase if it was?

That question was originally on the Arqade SE. It was then closed - the reason why being that it was off-topic, and should be moved to the GameDev SE.

Here is the close reason:

> Questions about Game Design and Development are off topic. This
> includes speculative questions about developer intent, with respect to
> both mechanics and narrative. You might want to ask over at GameDev.SE.

So I moved it. For roughly a day, it was on the GameDev SE. It was then closed - the reason why being that it was off-topic and should be moved to the Arqade SE. Sounds familiar? It does to me too.

So I moved it again. And it was closed again. For the same reason, and with the same suggestion.

---

So what site should it be on?

---

Here is a link to the same question on GameDev Meta, if you want it - [link](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2987/what-site-should-this-question-go-on)

Comment: As a moderator on GameDev.StackExchange, I'd recommend adjusting the default close reason text to avoid implying that speculative questions about developer intent might be on-topic on that site. We handle mainly questions about how to develop one's own new game or game mod, not questions about how/why/whether another developer might do something.

Comment: I don't see any statement on the GameDev version of the question that it should be moved to Arqade. Maybe it was a deleted comment. Some questions just don't belong on any of these sites. Each site determines the boundaries of their own topics, and that inevitably leads to gaps where a question is not on topic anywhere.

Answer (score 5):

This question is out of scope for both sites. It is in fact out of scope for the entire platform because it's overly broad and borders on speculation.

You should instead ask this on the Valorant subreddit. Or maybe just Google it, because honestly, most people on this site are just going to do that and invoke things like "Riot has an agreement with Valve's competitor Epic Games, so it's unlikely they'll come to Steam any time soon".